# How to Monochrome, Haze video Effect in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a lots of searching but i coudn't find the FFMPEG command for Monochrome effect and Haze Effect on video.

**Orignal**

[image: orignal]

**Haze Effect**

[image: Haze]

**Monochrome Effect**  (This is not sepia effect)

[image: Monochrome]

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: How to increase contrast via command ?, and what about monochrome effect.?

Comment: So I assume you want to increase the contrast for your effect you called "haze"? Did you use Photoshop to create these previews?

Comment: yes if it got same result then it ll be fine.

Comment: actually i found this effect from https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/ExoPlayerFilter, and it was a preview screenshot that and put it here. i am not making it in Photoshop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Monochrome

[image: monochrome] [image: original]

One method is to use the [hue](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hue) filter to desaturate.

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf hue=s=0 -c:a copy output
ffplay -vf hue=s=0 input
```

## De-haze (increase contrast)

[image: increase contrast] [image: original]

The [curves](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#curves) filter has several presets including a few that increase contrast. You can also make your own curves in Photoshop, export the ACV file and use it via the `psfile` option in the curves filter.

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf curves=preset=increase_contrast -c:a copy output
ffplay -vf curves=preset=increase_contrast input
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer @llogan, as per your answer monochrome effect is same as grayscale effect, can you make command like my monochrome out put?

Comment: and second thing How to use ffplay for live preview in android, i am really stuck to do that in android. any solution?

Comment: @NikunjParadva You are showing the sepia image from the link you provided (refer to the animation in the link), but you said you wanted monochrome which I assumed meant a grayscale.  Upon viewing the link again I see "monochrome" is actually a grayscale with more contrast. But now it seems you actually want sepia? I don't know anything about Android.